# How to provide tooltips for multiple line charts

Tags: rgraph

I'm converting existing code that displays a single line graph to display multiple line graphs at once.  I would like each line graph to have tooltips.  My code looks like this:

```
var line = new RGraph.Line('canvas', data).Set('tooltips', tips)
```

I can make multiple line graphs render by changing the *data* array from 1-dimension to 2-dimensions.
But I have also converted the *tips* array to 2-dimensions, and no tooltips are appearing at all.
Am I correct in assuming that the tips array is assumed to be 1-dimensional, and if so how do I specify tooltips for multiple line charts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give them as one big array. If you have them in multiple arrays you can use the JavaScript concat() function or you just add them together like below.

Here's an example without using the concat function:

```
new RGraph.Line({
    id: 'cvs',
    data: [
        [8,4,3],
        [9,8,1]
    ],
    options: {
        tooltips: ['A', 'B','C','D','E','F']
    }
}).draw();
```

And here's an example using concat():

```
tooltips_a     = ['A', 'B','C'];
tooltips_b     = ['D','E','F'];
tooltips_combo = tooltips_a.concat(tooltips_b);

new RGraph.Line({
    id: 'cvs',
    data: [
        [8,4,3],
        [9,8,1]
    ],
    options: {
        tooltips: tooltips_combo
    }
}).draw();
```

Comment: In addition, the tooltips must be strings (or they can't be numbers at least). I had a 2d array of numbers as input for the line graph, here is what I needed to do to get those numbers as corresponding tooltips:

`.set('tooltips', [].concat.apply([],data).map(String))`